# Validating Google User with OAuth C#

Tags: c#, google-api, oauth-2.0

I am looking to setup a process to validate a user from Google via OAuth, here is the expected behavior I want to create.

The user goes to a url that I provide, my application goes back to Google to see if they are logged in and authenticates them if they are not logged in, then have a Google "Log Me In" prompt appear and user completes the authentication.

After the user is authenticated, I want to collect their basic info (Email, First and Last Name) etc.

Once I have that, I will be doing other stuff, but I am good there.

I have read around, but I'm having a hard time getting my head around the whole OAuth Authentication process and how it plugs into Google. Can someone point me in the direction of what I am trying to get?

I have created a product in Google APIs and obtained a Client ID and secret, so I think I am ready to spin up a C# App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you need is wrapped up in this package : http://dotnetopenauth.net/

Look at their examples, and it will show you how to request parts of the user's information, and how to read them.

[EDIT]

```
      const string CallbackParameter = "callback";
      const string Endpoint = "https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id";

      using (var openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty())
      {
            var callbackUrl = new Uri(string.Format("{0}?{1}=true", _context.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri, CallbackParameter));
            var authRequest = openid.CreateRequest(Endpoint, new Realm(string.Format("{0}://{1}", _context.RequestUri.Scheme, _context.RequestUri.Authority)), callbackUrl);

            // Tell Google what we want
            var fetch = new FetchRequest();
            fetch.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email);
            fetch.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Name.First);
            fetch.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Name.Last);
            authRequest.AddExtension(fetch);

            var response = authRequest.RedirectingResponse;
            var location = response.Headers["Location"];

            var fetch = response.GetExtension<FetchResponse>();
            if (fetch != null)
            {
                Username = fetch.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email);
                Email = fetch.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email);
                FirstName = fetch.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Name.First);
                LastName = fetch.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Name.Last);
            }
      }
```

Comment: Thanks Justin I was able to get the address book. However, it looks like the process to get User info from the Directory API is different. Have you been able to do that?

Comment: Which information are you after specifically? User's first and last name, or something else?

Comment: Justin, first name, last name and email. If I can get the entire Profile that would be cool, but those 3 are most important.

Comment: @IsaacLevin - I have edited my answer to include an example. Let me know if you need any help understanding any of it.